# Drupal 7 - dynamic, collapsible, navigation bar/block/thing in the sidebar first

Tags: routes, navigation

Because a picture tells more than 1000 words.

Click here to see the image --> [OPEN IMAGE](http://verbeemen.sinners.be//a/Nieuwe%20map/example.png)
On the left side, you will see what I need.
On the right side, you see what I already have.

**The question:**

Is there a possibility for showing all the chapters in a navigation block (or something simular) like a navigationtree ? with collapsible nodes and meanwhile if you click on some of those chapters, the main page changes?

perhaps with jquery?
But I can't find any good documentation whereby I can say, That's what I need.

I hope that someone can help

Kind regards.

Dieter

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) or [Accordion Menu](http://drupal.org/project/accordion_menu) to get the desired effect.

IMO, DHTML Menu is simpler to use.